# C++ memcpy - defective address

Tags: c++, char, memcpy, unsigned

I have a vector that receives bytes from the network:

```
std:vector<unsigned char> data
```

I am trying to copy the address of the data into an unsigned char *[] array:

```
unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char [1024*1024]
```

I am trying to loop through it to find a valid data packet that I am looking for. The sample code is below.
When I try to do memcpy to process the data I get an error saying defective address.

```
//process data
        unsigned char * processPtr = NULL;
        memcpy((void *) processPtr, hdr, sizeof(Header));
        memcpy((void *) (processPtr + sizeof(Header)), (void *) ((unsigned char *) hdr + sizeof(Header))), hdr-> nubBytes);
```

Appreciate some help on this

header file:

```
typedef struct {
    uint word;
    int id;
    int nubBytes;
}Header;
    

#define WORD 0xA345
unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char[1024*1024];
Header *hdr;
int pktOffset;
cpp file:
Decode msg(std:vector<unsigned char> data, uint32_t bytesrcvd){
    pktOffset = 0;
    buffer = &data[0];
    rcvBufOffSet += bytesRcvd;
    numBytesInRecBuff += bytesRcvd;
    hdr = (Header *)(& buffer[pktOffset])
    if(hdr->word != WORD){    
        while(hdr->word != WORD && numBytesInRecBuff > 0)
            pktOffset++;
            numBytesInRecBuff--;
            hdr = (Header *)(& Buffer[pktOffset])
    }
    if(hdr->word != WORD){
        return;
    }
    else{
    //process data
        unsigned char * processPtr = NULL;
        memcpy((void *) processPtr, hdr, sizeof(Header));
        memcpy((void *) (processPtr + sizeof(Header)), (void *) ((unsigned char *) hdr + sizeof(Header))), hdr-> nubBytes);

processPacket((Header *)processPtr, unsigned char * (processPtr + + sizeof(Header)));
    }
}

processPacket(Header * hdrPtr, unsigned char * dataPtr){
    //further processing
}
```

Comment: `processPtr` is NULL. You cannot copy data into that address!

Comment: how would I fix this

Comment: The same way you manage _any_ memory. By allocating enough storage to receive the bytes you're copying into it.

Comment: is it like this? unsigned char * processPtr[1024*1024]; but how would I know the exact size for processPtr

Comment: Looking at your code, that's not the only problem. For example, you have a pointer `buffer` which points at a 1 MiB array of unsigned char, but in your `msg` function you overwrite that with a pointer to your _temporary_ `data` vector. So you just leaked memory, and replaced the pointer with another one that will be invalid when the function returns. I kinda stopped reading at that point. You probably need to take a step back and learn the basics of how to manipulate memory in C++.

Comment: And no, as per your comment, it's _not_ like that. What you wrote there is a stack-allocated array of 1048576 _pointers_. Very likely to overflow your stack with something like that.

Comment: What is the point of the `memcpy` in the first place? You already have a `Header*` in `hdr`. Just pass that to the function. The data is a the `sizeof(Header)` offset, so pass that as second argument. (That said there are multiple other problems with your code, the other comments mention a few, but not all.)

Comment: @user17732522 That `Header*` violates strict aliasing. The correct way to access the header in a byte stream is to copy it out.

Comment: @paddy That's already violated beforehand in the code, so I grouped it up with the other problems category in my edited comment.

Comment: where does it violate violates strict aliasing?

Comment: @jkafernando With `hdr->word`. The vector doesn't hold any `Header` object, yet you are trying to access part of it as if there was a `Header` object. The access of the member itself is not allowed and UB per standard and even if it was allowed, it would refer to a `unsigned char` object, not a `uint` and so that would be an aliasing violation. It may also be an alignment violation. The safe approach is to declare a local `Header` object, then `memcpy` from the vector into it and only then access the member of that `Header` object. The whole procedure shouldn't require any casts.